# Are there any mutant inhumans in marvel comics?

Tags: marvel, mutant, inhumans

Are there any mutant inhumans in marvel comics? (i.e. characters who are both mutants and inhumans)

I think that the Beyonder once claimed to be one, but it was retconned out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**

Inhuman and Mutant the genetic markers cancel each other like in [Luna Maximoff](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Luna_Maximoff_(Earth-616)) who is daughter of Quicksilver and Crystal leaving her a normal human.

There is [Beyonder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyonder)

[image]

> In a retcon of past events, Charles Xavier reveals to his fellow Illuminati members that in the original Secret War, he had attempted to mind-scan the Beyonder, revealing him as one of the Inhumans previously ruled over by fellow Illuminati member Black Bolt. Xavier also deduced the apparent secret behind the Beyonder's seemingly godlike abilities, which was that the Beyonder was not only an Inhuman but also a mutant, and the exposure of his mutant genes to Terrigen Mists had created an unprecedented power

But that was later retconned so there is no hybrid of Mutant and Inhuman

Comment: The Beyonder was later retconned to make that claim of his incorrect.

Comment: I know but that is the only instance in whole Marvel universe that dose two words come to same person even if it is later retconned

Comment: Quoting from the entry for "Secret Wars II" in *Secret Wars - The Official Guide to the Marvel Universe*,: "he allowed then to believe he was just a mutated inhuman".

Comment: I am aware of that just wanted to point out that it is only time that it was even considered. In my opinion Inhuman and Mutant the genetic markers cancel each other and there can  not be such a breed

Comment: I think one of the current X-Men comics is dealing with the concept.

Comment: not to my knowledge..

Comment: Extraordinary X-Men 004

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33924/discussion-between-vanja-vasiljevic-and-ibid).

Comment: Extraordinary X-Men 005 is out. (Though I haven't read it yet)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is — Luna Maximoff, she is daughter of Quicksilver and Crystal, and thus the first child to be born mutant & inhuman, a hybrid.
She is earth 616

Comment: Yes but Luna Maximoff is  normal human since her genetic markers cancel each other :)

Comment: welcome to scifi&fantasy se. Can you please provide evidence or proof of what you say here ?

Comment: There are 3 versions, in which the story of Earth 616, Luna was alive and was a major part of few issues